# Cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ in assignment in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm a beginner with C++, so I started to practice a little bit by writing my own `Vector` class.
It stores the number of rows and columns of the array and the elements are dynamic allocated.

```
template <class T> 
class Vector {
    private:
        unsigned int rows;
        unsigned int cols;
        T **elements;
    public:
        Vector(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        ~Vector();
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) {
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;

    this->elements = new T[this->rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
        this->elements[i] = new T[this->cols];
    }
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector() {
};
```

Here is the code. When I compile it (I create an object to test it: `Vector<int> test;`), I get the error: `"Cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ in assignment"`.

Why am I getting this error? I saw the multidimensional dynamic allocation example on web, on: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/63/

Comment: `new T[size]` returns `T*`. `elements` is a `T**`.

Comment: Read that reference you point to closely. You're missing a `*` somewhere in the first `new` expression. (And calling that thing a vector is a very strange choice. Vectors have one dimension, you're building a matrix.)

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: Thanks, Mat! I must more careful. I'm sorry for this idiot question.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Unless locality matters

Comment: please mark the problematic line (next time...)

Comment: Also you shouldn't leave the destructor as it is, you need to deallocate the memory allocated for `elements`

Comment: @EdS. No worse than a T**

Comment: @NeilKirk: I wouldn't replace it with a `T**`, I would replace it with a `vector<T>(rows * columns)` (if needed) and calculate the indices manually.  In most cases it probably doesn't matter of course.

Comment: @NeilKirk: but yeah, as a straight replacement you're 100% correct obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest error is that you're missing a '`*`' when allocating the array of pointers:

```
this->elements = new T*[this->rows];
```

aside from that:

1. Why are you defining a vector as a matrix with rows and columns?
2. Free memory after you've allocated and used when it's no longer needed
3. Accessors should be available

as a starting point take the following code:

```
template <class T> 
class Vector {
    public:
        unsigned int rows;
        unsigned int cols;
        T** elements;
        Vector(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        ~Vector();
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) {
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;

    this->elements = new T*[this->rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
        this->elements[i] = new T[this->cols];
    }
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector() {
    for(int i=0; i<this->rows;++i)
        delete[] this->elements[i];
    delete[] this->elements;
};


int main()
{
    Vector<int> obj(2,2);
    obj.elements[0][0] = 1;
    obj.elements[0][1] = 2;
    obj.elements[1][0] = 3;
    obj.elements[1][1] = 4;

    std::cout << obj.elements[0][0] << " " << obj.elements[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj.elements[1][0] << " " << obj.elements[1][1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/8VzDDp)</kbd>